# How to get my lighting like this video?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following this video to start learning about Unity.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VV3sSM0gjQ8

In this video, his scene is pretty dark aside from the lights that he put in, while my scene is like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/5c038a72e47e37234ab56cecba29bee0.png

No matter what I do with the light toggle, I can never get it like his. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing light in your scene. Click the light icon in your toolbar (its next to the shaded and 2D button) to see how the light looks in your scene.

For even better results use lightmapping. This means you put light in the scene and let the program calculate it for you. What you are using now is realtime lighting in your scene. Lightmapping will also enable you to use softshadows. Read the basics about it here: http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html

Comment: I am using that button, but it never gets to how the video looks.